# Powershell WPF observablecollection not updating wpf

Tags: wpf, powershell, binding

I am using a observablecollection to insert data for bindings on wpf GUI but it's not updating.

```
$global:myCollection = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection[Object]
[string]$global:MyLabelContent = 'Test'
$myCollection.Insert(0,[ref]$MyLabelContent)
```

This is the binding function i am using (from link below)

```
Function Set-Binding {
    Param(
        $Target,
        $TargetProperty,
        $Path,
        $Source
        )
 
    $Binding = New-Object System.Windows.Data.Binding
    $Binding.Path = $Path
    $Binding.Mode = [System.Windows.Data.BindingMode]::TwoWay
    If ($Source)
    {
        $Binding.Source = $Source
    }
    [void][System.Windows.Data.BindingOperations]::SetBinding($Target,$TargetProperty,$Binding)

}
```

Here is the actuall binding call:

```
Set-Binding -Target $MyLabel -TargetProperty $([System.Windows.Controls.Label]::ContentProperty) -path "[0].Value" -Source $MyCollection
```

And here's how i change the label content

```
[string]$global:MyLabelContent = $mystring
```

If i close and open the window again the label value is correctly set, so the binding is actually working...
What am i doing wrong? i'm already using the same system for menuitems checkboxes and it works.

https://smsagent.blog/2017/02/03/powershell-deepdive-wpf-data-binding-and-inotifypropertychanged/

Comment: What is not updating, your label? Maybe you need to add an CollectionChanged event for the ObservableCollection to redraw the label? Or use a different object type like a TextBox.

Comment: Yes the label is not updating, observablecollection has a inotifypropertychanged already implemented so it should be enough to redraw the label (is it?)
How would i tell it to redraw the label anyway?

Comment: The label has to support it too, not just the collection. I have a feeling the label doesn't support it, which is why you see things like your checkboxes updating, but not the label.